# Get-MailboxFolderPermission not matching for -User Guid

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

The where in this Get-MailboxFolderPermission used to match for GUID but it stopped working.
Now it will only match for -like $user.DisplayName.  What did I do to break this code?
How can I test what $_.User is seeing when it fails to match $user.Guid?

```
$users = Get-Mailbox |?{$_.ExchangeUserAccountControl-eq'AccountDisabled'}

foreach($user in $users){
    Write-Output "checking for $user"
    Get-Mailbox | 
    ForEach-Object {Get-MailboxFolderPermission $_":\calendar"} 
    | Where {$_.User -eq $user.GUID} | Select Identity, User, AccessRights

}
```

Working

```
foreach($user in $users){
     Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {Get-MailboxFolderPermission $_":\calendar"} | 
     Where {$_.User -like $user.DisplayName} | Select Identity, User, AccessRights
}
```

Comment: I don't think `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` ever returned the GUID in property `.User`.. If you want to compare against the guid, do `Where {$_.Guid -eq $user.GUID}`

Comment: @Theo, that was a good suggestion but it didn't to equal true when I ran it.
Strange thing is that it was working